# timeout with couchdb mapReduce when database is huge

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-3.x

Details:

- Apache CouchDB v. 3.1.1
- about 5 GB of twitter data have been dumped in partitions

Map reduce function that I have written:

```
{
 "_id": "_design/Info",
 "_rev": "13-c943aaf3b77b970f4e787be600dd240e",
 "views": {
   "trial-view": {
     "map": "function (doc) {\n  emit(doc.account_name, 1);\n}",
     "reduce": "_count"
   }
 },
 "language": "javascript",
 "options": {
   "partitioned": true
 }
}
```

when I am trying the following command in postman:

http://<server_ip>:5984/mydb/_partition/partition1/_design/Info/_view/trial-view?key="BT"&group=true

I am getting following error:

```
{
    "error": "timeout",
    "reason": "The request could not be processed in a reasonable amount of time."
}
```

Kindly help me how to apply mapReduce on such huge data?

Comment: Perhaps [Constantly getting errors when querying views: "The request could not be processed in a reasonable amount of time"](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I thought of answering my own question, after realizing my mistake. The answer to this is simple. It just needed more time, as the indexing takes a lot of time. you can see the metadata to see the db data being indexed.